# Recordset in VBA and C#

Tags: c#, vba

considering this code

```
  Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, cn2 As New ADODB.Connection
                        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
                        Dim connString As String
                        Dim SelectFieldName

                        Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
                        SelectFieldName = astrFields(intIx)
                        Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
                        Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, SelectFieldName))

strsql = select field from rs!tablename
```

Now i understand that this will work in VBA by getting the table name where the field is present.

I just want to know what would be C# equivalent for this piece of code?

Comment: Cleaned up tags (removed 'to', changed 'c' + 'sharp' to c#)

Comment: This question is a complete rewrite of the original question and title.

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense - I don't think it would compile or run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using System.Data.SqlClient;

//////now use following codes to retrieve data//////
String ConStr = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Database Name;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sqlcnn;
        SqlCommand sqlcmd;
        SqlDataReader sqldr;
        string plssql;
plssql = "select field from table_name where condition";
        sqlcnn = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        sqlcnn.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(plssql, sqlcnn);
        sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
String val=sqldr["field name"].ToString();
sqlcmd.Close();
sqlcnn.Close();
```

Chris
------
Convert your Excel spreadsheet into an online calculator.
http://www.spreadsheetconverter.com

Comment: This code may not be suitable for the question in its present form, because it is unclear whether the question refers to an SQL Server back-end or a Jet/Ace connection: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281784